# How to resolve PROG753 error in CICS?

Tags: db2, cobol, cics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOSZo.png)I executed nmy application in CICS region. After few maps, it throws PROG753 error and only few part of map is displayed. Can anyone help me with how to resolve this error?

I think in this image , "ITEMERR" is causing PROG753 error. Please check and give answer

Comment: Try doing a Google; i.e. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21165776

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC81881. I've always countered "X PROG" errors by finding invalid values in attributes or by finding "binary" data in the screen fields. Not sure anything is needed beyond not screwing your map up.

Comment: @IshitaSinha something has gone wrong somewhere in the program and overwritten something, or there is a typo with an attribute value, or there is an unexpected binary in a field sourced from a file. It is unrealistic to expect all that to be dumped here with a request to "find it for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have junk in the map output area in your program. Check that:

- You have cleared the output area before using it. Use MOVE LOW-VALUES to your area if it's Cobol, or equivalent statement in your language to initialize the output area to binary zeroes. Do it explicitly, do not hope that the area has been cleared for you.
- The data you move to the output area does not contain unprintable characters. Check your source areas - do not rely on the declarations only, the data may be redefined. If in doubt, dump the data out (EXEC CICS ENTER can help, but start with CEDF if you can.)
- Check that you haven't overwritten the attributes of your output fields.

Run your transaction under CEDF and stop before the problematic SEND MAP. Look at the FROM area. There must be junk there (unprintable characters,) find it using hexadecimal display and identify the reason of it getting there.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I moved LOW-VALUES before sending map and in some variables and it worked fine.